# Kotlin take(int).toList() omits first element

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a test LiveData that emits items every 2 seconds.
I convert it to flow and call take(3).toList() on it.

```
val list = newLiveData
            .asFlow()
            .onEach {
                println("Item ${it.status}")
            }
           .take(3)
           .toList()

println(list.joinToString {  "${it.status} " })
```

The implementation of that liveData makes it emit LOADING at first, then keep emitting SUCCESS, so I was expecting to see in the list:

```
LOADING, SUCCESS, SUCCESS
```

But for some reason it returns just

```
Item LOADING
Item SUCCESS
Item SUCCESS
SUCCESS , SUCCESS , SUCCESS
```

What's weird, it prints correct values in onEach and if I replace "take(3)" with "first()" I do indeed get the correct LOADING status.

Did anyone experience that behavior? It doesn't look like a proper one to me, so I ll open a bug report if it isn't a known case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it happened because my LiveData kept modifying one object and sending it instead of creating a new instance every time.

I had a LiveData similar to this:

```
class EmittingLiveData : LiveData<StateData<Int>>() {

    init {
        value = StateData()
    }

    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in StateData<Int>>) {
        startEmitting()
        super.observe(owner, observer)
    }

    override fun observeForever(observer: Observer<in StateData<Int>>) {
        startEmitting()
        super.observeForever(observer)
    }

    private fun startEmitting() {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
            value = value?.loading()

            async {
                while (this.isActive) {
                    delay(1000)
                    postValue(value?.success(0))
                }
            }.start()
        }
    }

}
```

And had to change posting value to

```
postValue(StateData<Int>().success(0))
```

A rookie - Object reference - issue, but I didn't expect that from flow. So maybe somebody else will find that helpful too :)

Credits for helping me out goes to **qwwdfsad** [github issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1725)